# Problem with Firing Events from Dynamic Dropdown List

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having a bit of a problem with an asp.net dropdown list box not working as it should. When
I select a listitem, I do get a postback but the handler procedure is not called. I think it is all coded correctly, but am I missing something? I done similar things may times with no problem.  I am at the point "I can't see the forest for the trees."  I posted a snippet of the code below.  Any help will be much appreciated.

dim ddl as DropdownList

```
ddl = New DropDownList
    With ddl
        .Items.Add("0")
        .Items.Add("1")
        .Items.Add("2")
        .Items.Add("3")
        .Items.Add("4")
        .Items.Add("5")
        .Items.Add("6")
        .Items.Add("7")
        .Items.Add("8")
        .Items.Add("9")
        .Items.Add("10")
        .SelectedIndex = ItemQuan
        .ID = "Quan_" & Count
        .CausesValidation = False
        .AutoPostBack = True
        AddHandler ddl.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ListBoxHandler
    End With
'
'
'
'
    Panel1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<td>" & vbCrLf))
    Panel1.Controls.Add(ddl)
    Panel1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</td>" & vbCrLf))


'test event handler
Private Sub ListboxHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    beep()
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, you not explained why you using code to add the ddl as opposed to a simple drag and drop of that control onto the web form? In other words, why write a bunch of code to do this when you can just drop in the dropdown list into the markup? I suppose there are "some" use cases to spend all that time and effort to write code, but it better be some really incredible reason for doing so.

Comment: To answer your question, the code is used top populate an html table with  as many as 15 items  - rows of pictures and data.

Comment: As noted, see my post below. However, what event are you using here? Page load will not work, but page init event should work for your code. So, call/use your posted code in the page init event. It should trigger the event when you select a ddl item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the code is used top populate an html table with as many as 15 items

Well, as I stated, that not all that great of a reason to try and "inject some controls.

There is a "boatload" of issue when you inject controls.

It becomes hard to wire up a event - those are resolved at compile time in most cases.

You don't get view state, so for ANY post-back, then you have to re-inject the controls each time.

And when you re-inject, then you have to re-load the list of choices, and WORSE also then re-set the existing choice (which also will not persit).

As I stated, you CAN cobbile together such code but you have to make a HUGE valid case to do so, and then we can start writing all that code.

As I stated, while PHP and other systems OFTEN do looping code to inject controls, asp.net web forms don't really work that way, and does not take all that kind to such approaches.

So, you want "x" or "n" rows of data, and want "x" or "n" number of combo boxes. (drop downs).

So, let's do that. We can use a repeater, listview, or even Gridview. I tend to like Listview, since then the markup tends to be far more "clean" markup.

But, we have limited time here. So, let's use a grid view.

For each row of the gridview, let's drop in a drop down list. It is a standard drop down list.

We set the Text and value field, and we add a event (on changed), and when the user changes that value, we will update the database based on that choice.

So, our mark up for the "table"

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
    CssClass="table table-hover"
    width="50%"
    >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Builder">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMaker" runat="server"
                    DataValueField="ID"
                    DataTextField="Maker"
                    OnTextChanged="ddlMaker_TextChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true"
                    width="180px" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FighterName" HeaderText="Fighter"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Engine" HeaderText="Engine"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Thrust" HeaderText="Thrust"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl = '<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' Width="140" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So, in above, note the ONE drop down - asp.net will do the "repeating" for us.

so, now our code to load the Gridview, but we ALSO have to setup + load the combo, and ALSO set the current existing selected value from that row of data.

So, we have this:

```
Dim rstMakers As DataTable   ' used during data bind
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    rstMakers = MyRst("SELECT ID, Maker FROM Manufactures")

    GridView1.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * FROM Fighters")
    GridView1.DataBind()


End Sub
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim gData As DataRowView = e.Row.DataItem
        Dim MDrop As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("ddlMaker")
        MDrop.DataSource = rstMakers
        MDrop.DataBind()
        MDrop.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select Maker", "0"))
        If Not IsDBNull(gData("Maker_ID")) Then
            MDrop.Text = gData("Maker_ID") ' Set selected value in ddl
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

And now the result is this:

[image]

So, now note how the ddl has a autopostback = true.

So, when the user changes the ddl, then we update the database.

That code is now this:

```
Protected Sub ddlMaker_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' user changed drop down, update database.
    Dim ddl As DropDownList = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = ddl.NamingContainer
    Dim PKID As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")
    Dim dChoice = ddl.SelectedItem.Value

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "UPDATE Fighters SET Maker_ID = @Maker
        WHERE ID = @ID"

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PKID
    If dChoice = "0" Then
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Maker", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
    Else
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Maker", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dChoice
    End If
    MyRstPU(cmdSQL)

End Sub
```

Of course, one gets very tired of typing in connecting string and command code, so for above, I have in my global "general" routines, these 2 helper routines I used:

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String, ByVal Optional strCon As String = "") As DataTable

    If strCon = "" Then
        strCon = My.Settings.TEST4
    End If

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            rstData.TableName = strSQL
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function

Public Function MyRstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand, ByVal Optional strCon As String = "") As DataTable

    If strCon = "" Then
        strCon = My.Settings.TEST4
    End If

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function


Public Sub MyRstPU(cmdSQL As SqlCommand, ByVal Optional strCon As String = "")

    If strCon = "" Then
        strCon = My.Settings.TEST4
    End If

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

So, once again, I fail to see the need, or "use case" of trying to inject a ddl into the markup, and as above shows, it going to be a whole lot less code and work anyway.

Comment: I actually used a dropdown list a couple of times and did not think of it.  The client simply wanted to change a text box to a DDL and I thought it would be an easy fix and bid accordingly.  I thought it would be a quick little job I'd do it in an hour or so.  I guess I learned my lesson the hard way.  I'm going to use your code sample and see what happens. I'll keep you posted. Thanks again.

Comment: I think the above does work better. While I "strong" suggested to use a repeater, or listview (or gridview), you CAN inject the ddl. You have to use the page "init" event, and if you do so, your posted code actually should trigger the ddl change event. However, as above shows, the ddl event when dropped into the gv shows how you can get the row index, the PK, and the ddl selected item. So, all in all, I still think letting the "system" repeat the rows is a better choice. As noted, you "can" inject your control, but you have to use the page init-event, and you need to set control's viewstate.

Comment: I want to thank you again for providing such detailed help.  I adapted your solution and it works great.  By the way, I also got tired of writing all the connection stuff and wrote a DLL about 10 years ago to make it simple I use a "using --- end using" coding method with the dll and never wory about leaving open connections.   It was a great solution to my problem.